# Keras on TF, how to get the loss values per example, without performing gradient descend?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm interested in examining loss values per example, using a `tf.keras.Model` instance, with the following restrictions:

1. Assuming I already called `model.compile()`, the information about the loss function is there - I don't want to explicitly define loss like in [this example from the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/eager/custom_training_walkthrough#define_the_loss_and_gradient_function)
2. Without performing gradient descend (I am aware of the option of accessing the loss in `tf.callback.Callback`s, but I don't want to perform GD)

Also, using a callback to get losses and then reloading the initial weights is not a valid solution, I want to avoid GD entirely.

So is there a way to achieve this? I would expect something that will look something like

```py
model = tf.keras.Sequential([....])
model.compile(optimizer=..., loss=...)

single_loss_value = model.get_loss(single_x, single_y)
batch_loss_valujes = model.get_loss(x, y)
```

Comment: So you want to get the loss before training the model? Just with the initial weights...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the loss of some samples you can use [`model.evaluate`](https://keras.io/models/model/#evaluate). There you can use `x` and `y`, as a single sample or a batch.

```py
model = tf.keras.Sequential([....])
model.compile(optimizer=..., loss=...)

single_loss_value = model.evaluate(single_x, single_y)
batch_loss_values = model.evaluate(x, y)
```